# Optimal discount algorithm (set packing with weight and quantity?)

Tags: algorithm, optimization, discount

Let's say we have some order with set of items:

```
(Id: quantity)
i1: 5
i2: 3
i3: 4
i4: 5
```

And some "offers" with discounts:

```
(Id: items - dicount)
o1: i2, i3 - 100
o2: i3, i4 - 50
o3: i4, i4 - 90
o4: i1, i2, i4 - 150
```

Each item can be applied to a single offer. But we can apply any number of offers to our order, as long as we have enough items.

Question is: is there any non-brute force algorithm to find most optimal combination of offers (to get biggest discount)?

At first glance this problem is very similar to weighted set pacliking problem, which is NP-compolete problem. But in this variation we have quantites of items and offers, So, I thought, may be there is a better approach than simple brute force enumeration?

Also, viewing some reallife examples, I just can't get rid of feeling that there is some logic/rules (although greedy approach isn't working at all)...

Answer (score 0):

What about a simplex algorithm? Z being the total discount. x,y,... the offers (multiplied by their discount). And the constraints would be the number of items (can't have more discounts than certain items). It should be more efficient than brute force. Some languages have this function implemented (scipy in python for instance).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.linprog-simplex.html

Comment: Looks to me more like a MIP than an LP (no fractional values allowed)

Comment: As far as I understand and as Erwin pointed out, Simplex method is supposed to be used for fractional values? Which means that it shouldn't be used for integer problems, or am I mistaken?

Comment: It can work well with integers, check section 6 "Algorithms" of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming for instance. I havn't used it often but i remember it working in some cases. I'd recommend trying it at least.

Comment: In general you can't solve a MIP with an LP solver. Lots of money is spent to develop highly sophisticated MIP solvers.

Comment: Hm... @ErwinKalvelagen, do you happen to have some recommendations on existing MIP algorithms that can potentially be applicable in my case?

Comment: does o4: i1, i2, i4 - 150 mean you nead i1 + i2 or need i1 or i2? I'll run a simplex for that case

Comment: @AntoineStock it means you need all of them: i1, i2 and i4.

Comment: I tried a few thing, it seems like the simplex only work if you have no duplicates in an offer (o1, o2, o4 OK; o3 makes it fail) (no integer solution)

Comment: I see. Anyway, thanks for yout effort, @AntoineStock. You've at least helped me to learn something new :)

Also, what constaints did you use? Here (http://simplex.tode.cz/en/), for examlple, what  values do use for x1,x2,x3,x4 in restrinction? Even if it's not right method in the end, It's interesting to at least undestand how to convert data correctly.

Comment: Choosing a MIP solver depends on many things. Eg free or a commercial products. Size and complexity of the model. Requirements for performance and support. Language bindings. Hardware requirements. Etc.

Comment: Here are the restrictions, https://imgur.com/a/LnXKdfP (it works in that case but it is luck)